# Calling in Angular2 Component Selectors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

**UPDATED POST**: for those asking, below is component code and service code for the the incident component.

Incident.Component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { IncidentService } from "./incident.service";
import { Incident } from "./incident";


@Component({ 
selector: "rpcs-incident",
templateUrl: "/app/incident.component.html",
providers: [IncidentService]
 })
export class IncidentComponent {
private incidents: Incident[];
private newIncident: Incident;
private _in: IncidentService;


constructor(incidentService: IncidentService) {
    this._in = incidentService;

    this._in.getAll()
        .subscribe(
        response => this.incidents = response,
        err => console.log("Error: ", err),
        () => console.log("Fetch incidents complete.", this.incidents)
        );
}


saveIncident(incident: Incident) {
    this._in.saveIncident(incident)
        .subscribe(
        response => this.incidents = response,
        err => console.log("Error: ", err),
        () => console.log("Save incident complete.", this.incidents)
        );

}

addIncident(incident: Incident) {
    this._in.addIncident(incident)
        .subscribe(
        response => this.incidents = response,
        err => console.log("Error: ", err),
        () => console.log("Add incident complete.", this.incidents)
        );

}

deleteIncident(incident: Incident) {
    this._in.deleteIncident(incident)
        .subscribe(
        response => this.incidents = response,
        err => console.log("Error: ", err),
        () => console.log("Delete incident complete.", this.incidents)
        );
}


}
```

Incident.Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { SpringfieldService } from "./springfield.service";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Incident } from "./incident";

@Injectable()
export class IncidentService extends SpringfieldService {
private url = this.baseUrl + "Incident";

constructor(private http: Http) {
    super();

}

getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getIncident(incidentId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.url, incidentId)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

saveIncident(incident: Incident) {
    return this.http.put(this.url, incident)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

addIncident(incident: Incident) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, incident)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

deleteIncident(incident: Incident) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url, incident)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

}
```

**ORIGINAL POST**: We are working on a major application rewrite utilizing Angular 2. Right now our appmodule currently looks like:

```
import { NgModule }      from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { NewsComponent } from "./news.component";
import { IncidentComponent } from "./incident.component";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ NewsComponent, IncidentComponent ],
  bootstrap: [NewsComponent, IncidentComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

We have the NewsComponent and IncidentComponent bootstrapped with selectors of "rpcs-news" and "rpcs-incident", respectively. Everything works properly when both selectors are called on the same page, but if I try to call rpcs-incident and leave out rpcs-news, the data from the database just won't show up until it's called.

Right now, this is a snippet of where I call in the selectors:

```
  <div id="incident" class="tab-pane fade">

    <h3>Incidents</h3>   
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <rpcs-incident>...Loading Incidents</rpcs-incident>            
    </div>        

</div>

<div id="news" class="tab-pane fade">

    <h3>News</h3>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <rpcs-news>...Loading News</rpcs-news>
     </div>


</div>
```

**My question is:** is there a way to use one selector without have to call in the other?

Comment: This sounds strange.. Can you show us the component code, and possibly service code where the data is loaded?

Comment: Mostly your observable to get the data is not subscribed to from the incidents component.

Comment: where are you adding your database call? If it is inside the component you are using `rpcs-news` it wont be called. Do add your service call flow.

Comment: @FredrikLundin I've added the component and service codes for the incident component.

Comment: @M.Straw hmm, still can't see anything wrong in your code. How do the two components and their templates differ in regards of loading and binding the data? (right now you are only showing us the incident component and no template)

Comment: @FredrikLundin right now they both get pulled via basic commands -- ie {{incident.IncidentDescription}} -- to show the  title and description of the data. However, when I try to just call the incidents, the news selector has to be on the page.